# How to get data from earlier blocks in ethereum BC via web3.py?

Tags: solidity, events, logs

I am trying to get data from earlier blocks/transactions.

I have created events and emitted them.

I can see the logs in the Remix IDE.

However, I cannot get the logs in web3.py. It only returns empty.

Is there any function that can return all of the logs generated by an event?

Here is my Smart Contract

```
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

contract UserRep {
    mapping(uint256 => User) users;
    uint256[] userIDList;
    
    struct User {
        uint256 id;
        //other attributes
       // string[] data;
        bool isMalicious;
        uint256 rep_value;
        
    }
    
    event reputationOfUser(uint256 userId, uint256 repVal );

    // Create a new user.
    function newUser(uint256 _id) public {
        // In a mapping, all elements are defined. They're just empty by default
        // So, just setting the id will create a new user;
        users[_id].id = _id;
        users[_id].rep_value = 50;
        
        userIDList.push(users[_id].id);
    }
    
    // Add reputation value of a user
    function increaseReputation(uint256 _id, uint256 _addRep) public {
        users[_id].rep_value = users[_id].rep_value + _addRep; 
        
        emit reputationOfUser(users[_id].id, users[_id].rep_value);
    }
    
    // Decrease the reputation value of a vehicle
    function decreaseReputation (uint256 _id, uint256 _decRep) public{
        if (users[_id].rep_value < 10){
            users[_id].isMalicious = true;
        }
        users[_id].rep_value = users[_id].rep_value - _decRep;
       // emit reputationOfUser(users[_id], users[_id].rep_value);
    }
    
    function getUserReputation(uint256 _id) public view returns (uint256){
        return users[_id].rep_value;
    }
    
    function isUserMal(uint256 _id) public view returns (bool){
        if (users[_id].rep_value < 10){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    function getAllUserIDs() public view returns  (uint256[] memory){
        return userIDList;
    }
    
    function noOfUsers() public view returns  (uint256){
        return userIDList.length;
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Hi! It would be helpful if you also provide the web3.py code you've been trying, and what errors you've gotten. Cheers!

Comment: Hi sir, I have tried [[  logs = deployed_contract.events.userGen().processReceipt(receipt) ]] ... 

It gives this error. [[ UserWarning: The log with transaction hash: b'\xed9^\xa00T\xa7\xa91\x02\x8f>\x12\x7f\xc2 \xd8\xd2>&\xbf\x8b\x8c\xfa\xf7\xdb\x05\xc1S:\xba\xa4' and logIndex: 0 encountered the following error during processing: LogTopicError(Expected 0 log topics.  Got 1). It has been discarded.
  warnings.warn(      ]]. 



The logs variable is an empty list.

Comment: If you know the proper way to return logs from a specific transaction / Block, then please share it with me.. My aim is to get a past value of a variable.